# error in non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the specific section causing the issue. I'm trying to include all these points, but I think I'm just not formatting it correctly. It also sometimes tells me I don't have a y aesthetic so if you could tell me what I need to add to fix that error, that would be helpful too.

```
ggplot(religion) + geom_bar(aes(x=comfort_practice_religion_umprompted, fill=comfort_practice_religion_umprompted, y = ..count../sum(..count..)) 
                             +labs(x="Comfort Level",y="Proportion",title="Comfort When Asked About Religious Beliefs")+
                              theme_classic()+ 
                              theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                                    axis.ticks.x = element_blank()))
```

Here's my reprex of my code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(forcats)
religion2 <- rename(religion, comfort_practice_religion_umprompted = How.comfortable.would.you.be.seeing.someone.who.practices.a.different.religion.from.you..Ask.you.about.your.religion..unprompted..in.conversation)
#> Error in rename(religion, comfort_practice_religion_umprompted = How.comfortable.would.you.be.seeing.someone.who.practices.a.different.religion.from.you..Ask.you.about.your.religion..unprompted..in.conversation): object 'religion' not found
ggplot(data=religion2) + geom_bar(aes(x=comfort_practice_religion_umprompted, fill=comfort_practice_religion_umprompted))
#> Error in ggplot(data = religion2): object 'religion2' not found

religion <- mutate(religion2, comfort_practice_religion_umprompted = fct_recode(comfort_practice_religion_umprompted, "No response" = ""))
#> Error in mutate(religion2, comfort_practice_religion_umprompted = fct_recode(comfort_practice_religion_umprompted, : object 'religion2' not found

religion <- mutate(religion2, comfort_practice_religion_umprompted = fct_relevel(comfort_practice_religion_umprompted, "Extremely comfortable","Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "No response"))
#> Error in mutate(religion2, comfort_practice_religion_umprompted = fct_relevel(comfort_practice_religion_umprompted, : object 'religion2' not found

ggplot(religion) + geom_bar(aes(x=comfort_practice_religion_umprompted, fill=comfort_practice_religion_umprompted, y=..count../sum(..count..)))
#> Error in ggplot(religion): object 'religion' not found
dput(religion2)                                
#> Error in dput(religion2): object 'religion2' not found
Created on 2021-11-29 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Here's my dput output

```r
c("Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not at all comfortable", "", "Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable",
```

I'm also getting an error in my barplot output. It's not letting me rename the pink bar as "no response." I tried to recode it but that didn't work.
[image: graph]

Comment: What happens, when the code does not have errors like `object 'religion' not found` etc? Also, the pink bar shows occurrence of "" in your object. Replace them with your desired string to have it in your plot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your question consist of multiple problems. You should focus on one problem in one question. I will adress the problem mentioned in the title: "error in non-numeric argument to binary operator". This is because in `ggplot` chain you have used plus (`+`) sign at the beginning of the line, not at the end as it should (look before the `labs()` function in your example). This is how it should look:

```
ggplot(religion) + geom_bar(aes(x=comfort_practice_religion_umprompted, fill=comfort_practice_religion_umprompted, y = ..count../sum(..count..)) +
                             labs(x="Comfort Level",y="Proportion",title="Comfort When Asked About Religious Beliefs")+
                              theme_classic()+ 
                              theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                                    axis.ticks.x = element_blank()))
```